# .asmx web services with ssl

Tags: web-services, asmx

Are there any special configuration settings you have to do to make a web service work with SSL?

Is there a way to force the service methods to authenticate using a username/password like I can do with a WCF service?

Answer (score 3):

1. No. SSL support provided by web server (IIS).
2. Yes. Just configure authentication through web.config